# Add title for x & y Axis in ios charts

Tags: objective-c, charts, ios-charts

Hi everybody i'm working with iOS Charts [iOS Charts danielgindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

here i'm struggling to add a title / units for x & y axis values. help me [image]

in this image in Yaxis having the title / unit like Power(bhp) & torque(ib-ft) like this iaso want to implement in both x & y Axis

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/2387 may be got help on this.

Answer (score -3):

You can add constraints to your graph in storyboard, e.g. make the chartview be 0.9 of width and height and center vertically and horizontally.

Label 1
Add it on the right side of the graph and these constraints:

a. align center y to superview

b. trailing space to superview as 0

c. leading space to graph as 0

Label 2
Add it on the left side of the graph and these constraints:

a. align center y to superview

b. leading space to superview as 0

c. trailing space to graph as 0

In code for these 2 labels this has to be added:

```
label.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( M_PI ) / 2 );
label2.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( M_PI ) / 2 );
```

Label 3
Add it at the bottom and these constraints:

a. align center x to superview

b. bottom space to superview as 0

c. top space to graph as 0

Result:

[image]